# Accuracy comparison Finite Difference, Finite Element & Boundary Element Method

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, finite-element-method

I'm quite a newbie to numerical simulation (heat transfer) and I'm quite confused about a sentence that our teacher said. He said

> "Finite Difference Method (FDM) and Boundary Element Method (BEM) are more accurate than Finite Element Method (FEM). Moreover, in FDM and BEM, the energy is always conserved. However in FEM, it's not always."

He didn't explain why and then disappeared. Maybe I misheard or missed something in his class. Based on his statement, I have following questions.

1. Is his statement really true?
2. I understand that both FEM and BEM start from the weak form of the PDE, e.g. 
   \begin{equation}
   \ \int_{\Omega} w(-\nabla \cdot (-\lambda \nabla T)) d\Omega =0. 
   \end{equation} 
   By definition, the test function `w` in the weak form should be arbitrary. However, in both FEM and BEM, some specific test functions are selected (e.g. Galerkin's method in FEM and Green's function in BEM). Does this mean that the equation above only holds with the chosen test function? If I use other test functions to test the accuracy, will the weak form equation not hold? Does this mean that the energy is not conserved in both methods?

It would be also appreciated if anyone could recommend some literatures or books addressing this question.

Comment: Welcome to MathStackExchange. Consider editing your question to make it easier for people to respond. I think you are asking too many questions at once. Particularly "What if I use other test functions to test the accuracy?" might reuqire a big discussion rather than an *answer*. Additionally, by BEM you mean Boundary Element Method? Even if the tag is not available, it is good practice to make explicit what acronyms you are using, these things are not always as standardized as we think.

Comment: @Mefitico thank you for your tip. I will change the abbreviation in my post. I think the 2nd question is a complementary question to the 1st question. I was just wondering whether the energy conservation holds when using Finite Element Method and Boundary Element Method.

Comment: For starters, using the finite element method means choosing a finite dimensional space where you will state and solve a discrete problem. This can be done in many different ways and, in some cases, you can even do it  in such a way that you obtain the same linear system as in finite differences. So I'd say that the statement, as it is, is false.

Comment: @PierreCarre how about if I use Galerkin's method? Does the energy conservation hold?

Comment: I agree with PierreCarre _that the statement, as it is, is false_. With any decent FEM, conservation laws should always hold, as well as with any decent FDM, FVM or BEM. But, quite unfortunately, I have seen numerical methods (in the past) where even conservation of mass has not been guaranteed ! Hopefully such methods have become extinct nowadays; I'm not completely sure, though.